# Customize upload folder for sites

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I´ve just installed a wordpress multisite installation (version 4.2.1) with mapped domains.

For each site the url for an uploaded image which is shown in the browser is `http://URL/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITENUMBER/DATE/...` and the folder is `/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITENUMBER/DATE/...`.
But I want to use the local path `/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/sites/SITENUMBER/...` and want to see in the browser `http://URL/wp-content/uploads/DATE/...` (like in a single wordpress site).

I´ve read a much about that and I think I know that the option "UPLOAD URL PATH" normally should rewrite this, doesn´t it? But for me it doesn´t work. How could I customize wordpress to fit it?

Update: I´ve found out that in functions.php are define that multisites will get a rewrite of the URL:

```
// If multisite (and if not the main site in a post-MU network)
if ( is_multisite() && ! ( is_main_network() && is_main_site() && defined( 'MULTISITE' ) ) ) {

if ( ! get_site_option( 'ms_files_rewriting' ) ) {
/*
* If ms-files rewriting is disabled (networks created post-3.5), it is fairly
* straightforward: Append sites/%d if we're not on the main site (for post-MU
* networks). (The extra directory prevents a four-digit ID from conflicting with
* a year-based directory for the main site. But if a MU-era network has disabled
* ms-files rewriting manually, they don't need the extra directory, as they never
* had wp-content/uploads for the main site.)
*/

    if ( defined( 'MULTISITE' ) )
        $ms_dir = '/sites/' . get_current_blog_id();
    else
        $ms_dir = '/' . get_current_blog_id();

    $dir .= $ms_dir;
    $url .= $ms_dir;
    ...
}}
```

But I didn´t know how I could change this to get the needed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change your upload directory in WordPress using below function.

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'upload_dir_filter' );

function upload_dir_filter( $upload ) {
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $upload_dir = $dir['basedir'] . '/uploads/date';
    $upload_url = $dir['baseurl'] . '/uploads/date';

    wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir );  //WordPress will check if the dir exists and can write to it.
    $upload['path'] = $upload_dir;
    $upload['url']  = $upload_url;

        return $upload;
    }
```

Comment: Well, I don´t want to change the upload dir because each site should have an own upload path. Are you shure this will work in a multisite installation?

Comment: @UsersUser  you should add this on your theme function.php it will work on multisite installation

Comment: Is there a theme indendent solution possible?

Comment: You can make this function a plugin and drop it on mu-plugins folder, which stands for "must use plugins". On this folder it will never be disabled unless you remove it from the server.

Comment: Also, take a look on this item for wp-config which is an override on changing the default uploads folder name: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder

Comment: @GusFune editing wp_config will not work on multisite installation and adding the function as a mu plugin also not work - i get the following error: `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'baseurl' in .../mu-plugins/upload.php on line xx` - for _baseurl_ and _basedir_